# Interaction in R to SAS

Tags: r, interaction, sas

I am trying to convert an R model to a SAS model. I have interaction terms in the model as below:

```
I((PIC == 'x') * UR_log_lead6)
I((FAC == 'CE') * UR_log_lead6)
```

Does anyone know how this interaction works in SAS? Sorry my R skills are very limited.

I understand that interaction "*" in R is different to "*" in SAS. * in SAS translates to ":" in R and "*" in R translates to each individual terms + the interaction term (ie a*b=a+b+a:b in R) - is that correct and if so what does I(a*b) do? and what would that be?

Comment: It looks like that interaction model was created by someone who doesn't really understand how interactions and factor variables should be used in R. You might want to start from the beginning and explain what is really desired.

Answer (score 1):

You should take @42's advice and start from scratch.

1. Yes, "*" in SAS translates to ":" in R.
2. A|B in SAS implies A B A*B in SAS and the equivalent in R is
   A*B which translates to A + B + A:B.
3. In R `I(a*b)` means "multiply a times b" and use that as a variable in the model.
   Another example is `I(a^2`) which creates a squared in the model without
   having to have an a2 = a^2 in the data.

Comment: And 4) in an R formula `a*b` could mean at least three different things depending on the structure of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two continuous factors. You can always just create a product term variable in a data step. In a model line for a proc glm step, the same multiplicative notation can be used to specify interactions.

Comment: Thanks Adam, what does I(...*...)mean? I am trying to use a binary indicator for FAC='CE' and * to interact with UR_log_lead6.

Comment: Interaction terms are just product terms. If you were to create a interaction term in a data step, you would literally be multiplying the two main level effects together. Binary terms need not be coded as factors, since numerical 0/1 codings produce identical inference. The `*` is a convenient shorthand used in both SAS and R to denote the mathematical construction of a product term.

Comment: If you are trying to educate someone about equivalencies between R factors and their analog in SAS, I would have expected some discussion of the CLASS statement.

Comment: It doesn't look that way to me at all. Testing for equality to "x" appears to imply that one of the vectors is either character or factor, and this in turn implies that one needs to know the exact data context, .... which is so far entirely mysterious.